# Unable to debug from VS2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to compile the code below but and am now unable to debug. Any idea ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AnalysisServices;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace SqlBi.Tools {
    /// <summary>
    /// MdxScriptUpdater handles the manage of custom 
    /// MDX statements into an existing cube
    /// Use in this way:
    /// 1 - Create a MdxScriptUpdater instance specifying a server name
    /// 2 - Add MDX statements you want to put into the cube adding strings to MdxCommands collection
    /// 3 - Call Update method passing the name of database and cube - you have to use object IDs instead of displayed names!
    /// </summary>
    public class MdxScriptUpdater : IDisposable {
        /// <summary>
        /// Type of update
        /// </summary>
        public enum UpdateType {
            /// <summary>
            /// Delete existing commands and insert the new ones
            /// </summary>
            DeleteAndInsert, 
            /// <summary>
            /// Only delete existing commands
            /// </summary>
            DeleteOnly, 
            /// <summary>
            /// Only insert new commands (be careful, you can create duplicates!)
            /// </summary>
            InsertOnly
        };

        private string _marker = "/* AUTO-GENERATED */";
        private Server _serverConnection = null;
        private bool _ownedServer = false;
        private List<string> _mdxCommands;

        /// <summary>
        /// Marker is a comment that is put in front of the MDX statement to recognize managed MDX statements
        /// </summary>
        public string Marker {
            get { return this._marker; }
            set { this._marker = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is the connection to the server. 
        /// It is auto generated by the constructor but you can use your own connection, if you want
        /// </summary>
        public Server ServerConnection {
            get { return this._serverConnection; }
            set {
                if (this._serverConnection != null && _ownedServer) {
                    try {
                        this.Dispose();
                    }
                    finally {
                        _ownedServer = false;
                    }
                }
                this.ServerConnection = value;
                _ownedServer = true;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// List of Mdx statements to add/update into the cube
        /// Populate the list before calling the Update(...) method
        /// </summary>
        public List<string> MdxCommands {
            get { return this._mdxCommands; }
            set { this._mdxCommands = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Default constructor - connection is not defined
        /// </summary>
        public MdxScriptUpdater() {
            this._mdxCommands = new List<string>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor that connects to the specified server
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="serverName">Name of the Analsys Services server instance (SERVERNAME or SERVERNAME\INSTANCE)</param>
        public MdxScriptUpdater( string serverName ) : this() {
            this._serverConnection = new Server();
            this.ServerConnection.Connect( serverName );
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Apply updates to the specified cube
        /// Deletes existing managed Mdx commands and insert the ones in MdxCommands string collection
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="databaseName">Name (ID) of the Database</param>
        /// <param name="cubeName">Name (ID) of the Cube</param>
        public void Update( string databaseName, string cubeName ) {
            Update( databaseName, cubeName, UpdateType.DeleteAndInsert );
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Apply updates to the specified cube
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="databaseName">Name (ID) of the Database</param>
        /// <param name="cubeName">Name (ID) of the Cube</param>
        /// <param name="updateType">Type of update</param>
        public void Update( string databaseName, string cubeName, UpdateType updateType ) {
            Database db = ServerConnection.Databases[databaseName];
            Cube cube = db.Cubes[cubeName];
            Update( cube, updateType );
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Apply updates to the specified cube
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cube">Cube object</param>
        public void Update( Cube cube ) {
            Update( cube, UpdateType.DeleteAndInsert );
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Apply updates to the specified cube
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cube">Cube object</param>
        /// <param name="updateType">Type of update</param>
        public void Update( Cube cube, UpdateType updateType ) {
            // Look for the default MDX Script object
            foreach( MdxScript script in cube.MdxScripts) {
                if (script.DefaultScript) {
                    Update( script, updateType );
                    cube.Update();
                    return;
                }
            }
            throw new MdxScriptUpdaterException( "Default script not found" );
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Update an MdxScript
        /// Deletes existing managed Mdx commands and insert the ones in MdxCommands string collection
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="script">MdxScript to update</param>
        /// <param name="updateType">Type of update</param>
        public void Update( MdxScript script, UpdateType updateType ) {
            if (updateType == UpdateType.DeleteAndInsert || updateType == UpdateType.DeleteOnly) {
                DeleteMarkedCommands( script );
            }
            if (updateType == UpdateType.DeleteAndInsert || updateType == UpdateType.InsertOnly) {
                InsertMarkedCommands( script );
            }
            script.Update();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deletes existing managed Mdx commands using default Marker comment string
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="script">MdxScript to update</param>
        public void DeleteMarkedCommands( MdxScript script ) {
            DeleteMarkedCommands( script, Marker );
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deletes existing managed Mdx commands using a custom Marker comment string
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="script">MdxScript to update</param>
        /// <param name="marker">Custom marker comment string</param>
        public static void DeleteMarkedCommands( MdxScript script, string marker ) {
            for( int i = script.Commands.Count - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
                if (script.Commands[i].Text.Contains( marker )) {
                    script.Commands.RemoveAt( i );
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Insert managed commands of MdxCommands string collection
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="script">MdxScript to update</param>
        public void InsertMarkedCommands( MdxScript script ) {
            InsertMarkedCommands( script, this.MdxCommands, Marker );
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Insert managed commands of a custom string collection
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="script">MdxScript to update</param>
        /// <param name="commands">Custom string collection of Mdx commands to insert</param>
        public void InsertMarkedCommands( MdxScript script, IEnumerable<string> commands ) {
            InsertMarkedCommands( script, commands, Marker );
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Insert managed commands of MdxCommands string collection using a custom Marker comment string
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="script">MdxScript to update</param>
        /// <param name="marker">Custom marker comment string</param>
        public void InsertMarkedCommands( MdxScript script, string marker ) {
            InsertMarkedCommands( script, this.MdxCommands, marker );
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Insert managed commands of a string collection using a custom Marker comment string
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="script">MdxScript to update</param>
        /// <param name="commands">Custom string collection of Mdx commands to insert</param>
        /// <param name="marker">Custom marker comment string</param>
        public static void InsertMarkedCommands( MdxScript script, IEnumerable<string> commands, string marker ) {
            foreach( string mdxCommand in commands ) {
                Command cmd = new Command();
                cmd.Text = marker + mdxCommand;
                script.Commands.Add( cmd );
            }
        }

        #region IDisposable Members

        public void Dispose() {
            if (this.ServerConnection != null && _ownedServer) {
                this.ServerConnection.Disconnect();
                this.ServerConnection.Dispose();
            }
            // Write directly to private member, skip the property setter
            this._serverConnection = null;
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public class MdxScriptUpdaterException : Exception {
        public MdxScriptUpdaterException() : base() {}
        public MdxScriptUpdaterException( string message ) : base( message ) {}
        public MdxScriptUpdaterException( string message, Exception innerException ) : base( message, innerException ) {}
        protected MdxScriptUpdaterException( SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context ) : base( info, context ) {}
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using SqlBi.Tools;
using System.IO;

namespace SqlBi.Tools {
    class DemoMdxScriptUpdater {
        static void Main( string[] args ) {
            Demo();
        }
        static void Demo() {
            MdxScriptUpdater updater = new MdxScriptUpdater("test");

            string ScriptMdx = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\\ScriptMdx.txt");
            //Console.WriteLine("--- Contents of file.txt: ---");
            //Console.WriteLine(ScriptMdx);
            updater.MdxCommands.Add(ScriptMdx);

            updater.Update("BI", "BI1"); 

        }
    }
}
```

> 'MdxScriptUpdater.vshost.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'MdxScriptUpdater.vshost.exe' (Managed
>   (v2.0.50727)): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'MdxScriptUpdater.vshost.exe' (Managed
>   (v2.0.50727)): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'MdxScriptUpdater.vshost.exe' (Managed
>   (v2.0.50727)): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'MdxScriptUpdater.vshost.exe' (Managed
>   (v2.0.50727)): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'MdxScriptUpdater.vshost.exe' (Managed
>   (v2.0.50727)): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'MdxScriptUpdater.vshost.exe' (Managed
>   (v2.0.50727)): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'MdxScriptUpdater.vshost.exe' (Managed
>   (v2.0.50727)): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\Desktop\HaysDW\05.Tools\MdxScriptUpdater\bin\Debug\MdxScriptUpdater.vshost.exe',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'MdxScriptUpdater.vshost.exe' (Managed
>   (v2.0.50727)): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.AnalysisServices\11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'MdxScriptUpdater.vshost.exe' (Managed
>   (v2.0.50727)): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient\11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'MdxScriptUpdater.vshost.exe' (Managed
>   (v2.0.50727)): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'MdxScriptUpdater.vshost.exe' (Managed
>   (v2.0.50727)): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. The thread 'vshost.NotifyLoad' (0x5840) has
>   exited with code 0 (0x0). The thread 'vshost.LoadReference' (0x7b2c)
>   has exited with code 0 (0x0). 'MdxScriptUpdater.vshost.exe' (Managed
>   (v2.0.50727)): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\Desktop\HaysDW\05.Tools\MdxScriptUpdater\bin\Debug\MdxScriptUpdater.exe',
>   Symbols loaded. 'MdxScriptUpdater.vshost.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)):
>   Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. The thread 'vshost.RunParkingWindow'
>   (0x6e88) has exited with code 0 (0x0). The thread '' (0x4a9c) has
>   exited with code 0 (0x0). The program '[4784]
>   MdxScriptUpdater.vshost.exe: Managed (v2.0.50727)' has exited with
>   code 0 (0x0). The program '[4784] MdxScriptUpdater.vshost.exe: Program
>   Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: So it won't compile at all and this is the only error message you can see?

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid yes .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to take a punt than you have disabled the 'Just My Code' check box somehow in Tools -> Options -> Debugger

[image: Visual Studio Debug Options]

Comment: well, the output is littered with `Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.`. Wouldn't that mean that it is not disabled..?

Comment: @Alex , I did like you mentioned but it didn't work , I got the same error .

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Alex's answer,

Unchecking "Enable Just my code (Managed only)" in Tools -> options -> Debugging -> General option could do the trick. refer [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/74a90d81-4687-4ffb-aaaf-6913f1206dba/skipped-loading-symbols-module-is-optimized-and-the-debugger-option-just-my-code-is-enabled?forum=vsdebug) link for other options to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

If neither of it works, Try this;

Load PDB files on to the Microsoft Symbol Server by checking the checkbox in the Tools>Debugging>Symbols.

Further if the directory has  a path for Cache, something like this: C:\Users\Machine\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache
Then Empty the Symbol Cache and Build the solution.

It worked for me, try for yours.